# Axios module import issue: Module not found: Can't resolve 'debug' in 'follow-redirects'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, debugging, next.js, axios

I am using Next.js 13.4.2 and Axios 1.4.0 for my current project and encountering an issue while running my project in dev mode. As soon as I import axios (still everything fine) and then try to fetch som data, it shows me a warn inside the console:

Module not found: Can't resolve 'debug' in '\node_modules\follow-redirects'

The error suggests using './debug' instead of 'debug' and mentions that requests starting with a name are treated as module requests. However, changing the source code is not an option for me as I dont wanna perform code changes inside node_moduels

Here is the import trace for the requested module:

```
./node_modules/follow-redirects/debug.js
./node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js
./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js
./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/adapters.js
./node_modules/axios/lib/core/dispatchRequest.js
./node_modules/axios/lib/core/Axios.js
./node_modules/axios/lib/axios.js
./node_modules/axios/index.js
./src/components/login/LoginForm.tsx
```

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue without modifying the source code. I've heard there is a resolve option called 'preferRelative' that might help in resolving these kinds of requests in the current directory. Can someone please explain how to use this resolve option or provide an alternative solution? Thank you.

Comment: Having the same problem, It's a shame nobody answered this